# Troubles with the reference

Tags: bibtex, natbib

When I try to insert references from a report.bib file, a question mark appears in the paper.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you run the normal cycle `latex > bibtex (or biber) > latex (twice)`?

Comment: Sorry, I am newer to LaTex. What is that?

Comment: there will have been a message on the terminal at the end to run biber on your document and then run latex again (some editors do this for you running pdflatex and biber and pdflatex on a single command, some you need to do the steps yourself)

Comment: Hard to say something without more details, but as has been mentioned above, this *could* be a symptom of not running BibTeX correctly (or of BibTeX aborting the run with an error). Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. If that (i.e. running BibTeX correctly) doesn't work, you may want to share some more details about your document and in particular the citation and bibliography setup. This is best done in a so-called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), a short yet fully compilable example document that contains only the relevant code for your problem.